# Issues installing GDAL with PostgreSQL

Tags: gdal, postgresql

I'm trying to install gdal-1.11.0 on CentOS 6 machine. 
Following the instructions, this is my config

```
./configure --prefix /usr/local  --with-fgdb=/usr/local/FileGDB_API --with-pg=/usr/pgsql-9.3/bin/pg_config
```

As the configure process runs, I see this in the output:

```
checking for PostgreSQL... yes
```

However, at the end of the configure output, I see this:

```
PostgreSQL support:        no
```

PostgreSQL 9.3 is up and running with postgis on it, the path to pg_config is correct. I know the configure is reading it, because if I put a bad path in --with-pg, it complains... 
I had prior installs of earlier versions of GDAL, and GDAL 1.11 without postgreSQL before I realized that I need to build it with PostgreSQL support. 
What am I missing?

Comment: Do you have postgresql-devel installed too?

Comment: I do not! Installing it now...

Comment: You should post it as an answer and accept it as best answer. Glad you solved your problem!

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue on Ubuntu 16.04 and has to install `libpq-dev` with `sudo apt install libpq-dev`.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problems with GDAL 3.0.1 with RHEL 7.x. Here are few notes, if you have problems to compile PostgreSQL Driver:

On 3.0.1 compile parameter for PostgreSQL has been change:

```
./configure --help | grep Post
  --with-pg=ARG           Include PostgreSQL GDAL/OGR Support (ARG=yes,no)
```

So, you can't give anymore path to `pg_config`. GDAL is now relating to `pkg-config` (rather than `pg_config`). Note: https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/issues/1412

For some reason PostgreSQL 11 is installing necessary .pc -files (like `libpq.pc`) to directory which is unknown by pkg-config (not into `/usr/lib64/pkgconfig` or `/usr/share/pkgconfig`)

Before running `./configure`, add following enviroment variable:

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/pgsql-11/lib/pkgconfig/
```

Hope this helps somebody somewhere sometime,

P

Comment: export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/pgsql-10/lib/pkgconfig/ Helped me past a hurdle. Thanks!